# How can i use Regexp for parsing data

Tags: c#, .net, regex

What is the regexp pattern to achieve the following task

data format (pattern)

**anyword:anycharcters;**

sample input

```
msg:"c# 6.0 is good";sid:201;classtype:object oriented;.net,ado.net,other messages
```

expected output (match groups)

```
msg:"c# 6.0 is good"; ----------> 1
sid:201;--------------------->2
classtype:object oriented;---------->3
```

Comment: [String.split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split\(v=vs.110\).aspx) probably works more easily than delving into regexps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string g = @"msg:""c# 6.0 is good"";sid:201;classtype:object oriented;.net,ado.net,other messages";

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(g, @"(.*?):([^;]*?;)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))

Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value + "--------"+match.Groups[2].Value);
```

output:

```
msg--------"c# 6.0 is good";
sid--------201;
classtype--------object oriented;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a regex matcher here.  Instead, you can just try splitting the string by a semicolon delimeter:

```
string value = "msg:\"c# 6.0 is good\";sid:201;classtype:object oriented;.net,ado.net,other messages";
string[] lines = Regex.Split(value, ";");

foreach (string line in lines) {
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

## Demo

Comment: Why answering with an imperative code when the OP wants a regex solution ? have you thought that he might want to learn Regex and hence he tagged the question as Regex ? for splitting you don't need Regex.Split.

Comment: @Royi Your answer has using a matcher covered.  In practice, we would most likely split here by a delimeter.

Comment: OP specifically said _(match groups)_ . Not all questions are XY problems. it might be a simplifications of a more complex problem. Not to mention that it's way overhead to use regex for split.

Answer (score 1):

If you really favour a regex solution, you could use:

```
[^;]+;
# not a ; 1+
# a ;
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/V2mA2l/1/). Otherwise just split on the semicolon.